# c++ wrong background colors in console after 10'000 lines

Tags: c++, windows, colors, background, console

After printing more lines than Height of the "Screen Buffor Size" (by default 300, up to the maximum of 9999) the remainder of the first white line has a yellow background. Information is displayed continuously and important parts are highlighted, therefore `system("cls")` is not a preferred option. Is there any other solution? *Windows 7, MSVS Community 2017, x86 & x64*

```
#include "Windows.h"
#include "stdio.h"

class Console {
    HANDLE h;
public:
    Console() { h = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); }
    void ChangeColor(WORD wColor) {
        if (h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) SetConsoleTextAttribute(h, wColor);
    }
} console;

int main() {
    for (int i = 0;; i += 4) {
        console.ChangeColor(224);
        printf("highligted yellow, line = %5d\n", i);

        console.ChangeColor(240);
        printf("plane white\n\n\n");

        if (i %  1000 == 0) getchar();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you really want to make a GUI, I suggest you actually make a GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think console buffer gets reused and color attribute that you've set will mess with new lines. You should assign black and handle EOL separately.

```
for (int i = 0;; i += 4)
{
    console.ChangeColor(224);
    printf("highligted yellow, line = %d", i);
    console.ChangeColor(0);
    printf("\n");
    console.ChangeColor(240);
    printf("plane white");
    console.ChangeColor(0);
    printf("\n\n\n");
    if (0 == (i %  1000)) getchar();
}
```

Comment: Eww, more Yoda conditionals.